# Appending an integer to dictionary keys, python

Tags: python, key

I have a python dictionary with several keys.

Example:

`dicOut = dict(list(zip(keys, values)))`

`for i in keys:`
`print(i)`

out:

- Trees
- Cars
- People
- .... x n keys

I wish to assign a number in front.

- 1. Trees
- 2. Cars
- 3. People
- 4. .... x n keys

How do I make the for loop"

so far:

```
 k = len(keys)
 x = range (1,k+1)
 for j in x:
  for k in keys:
     n= j, '-', k
     print(n)
```

However it print all e.g. 3 keys 3 time. How to stop it at just e.g. e distinct keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,k in enumerate(dicOut, start=1):
    print(i,k)
```

Comment: Actually, you want `enumerate(dicOut, start=1)`.  Otherwise, you'll get 0, 1, 2, etc instead of the 1, 2, 3, requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for key in dict:
     print(key, '. ', dict[key])
```